# What feerate estimation APIs are there?

Tags: transaction-fees, api, fee-estimation

Some company's, block explorers and payment processors offer a public API for feerate estimations. Is there a list of publicly available feerate estimation APIs?

Comment: You seem to have asked this question so that you could promote your own blog post/content.

Comment: I've created this question to share my knowledge about this topic with the community. [This is encouraged by the StackExchange platform](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). While I disclose that the answer is based on other content by me, there there is no need to open / read it to find the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've listed some public feerate APIs by block explorers and payment processors below. Purposefully leaving out APIs from wallets, since they don't advertise their APIs. I leave out Bitcoin Core's `estimatesmartfee` RPC, which I don't consider public (*as in reachable over the web by everyone*).

The list is sorted lexicographically. Disclosure: This Q&A is based on a [blog post](https://b10c.me/A-list-of-public-feerate-estimator-APIs/) by me.

---

#### bitcoiner.live API

URL: https://bitcoiner.live/api/fees/estimates/latest
Note: Estimates for confirmation in 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 12 and 24 hours.
Unit: `sat/vByte`

---

#### Bitgo API

URL: https://www.bitgo.com/api/v2/btc/tx/fee
Note: Estimates for different block targets based on current mempool.
Unit: `sat/kB`

---

#### Bitpay Insight API

URL: https://insight.bitpay.com/api/utils/estimatefee?nbBlocks=2,4,6
Note: Estimates for different block targets based on `nbBlocks` parameter.
Unit: `BTC/kB`

---

#### Blockchain.info API

URL: https://api.blockchain.info/mempool/fees
Note: Estimates for a *regular* and *priority* feerate are provided.
Unit: `sat/Byte`

---

#### Blockchair API

URL: https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/stats
Note: A single estimate for a feerate is provided.
Unit: `sat/Byte`

---

#### BlockCypher API

URL: https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main
Note: Estimates for a *high*, *medium* and *low* feerate are provided.
Unit: **`sat/kB`**

---

#### Blockstream.info API

URL: https://blockstream.info/api/fee-estimates
Note: Estimates for confirmation in 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 20, 144, 504 and 1008 blocks.
Unit: `sat/vByte`

---

#### BTC.com API

URL: https://btc.com/service/fees/distribution
Note: A single estimate for a 'one block' feerate is provided.
Unit: `sat/vByte`

---

#### earn.com API

URL: https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/api/v1/fees/recommended
Note: Estimates for the fastest confirmation, a confirmation in half an hour and a hour are provided.
Unit: `sat/vByte`